# Project 'davis_ros_driver' tried to find library 'pthread'. The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the code

> catkin build davis_ros_driver

from https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_dvs_ros, I met an error:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/roscpp/cmake/roscppConfig.cmake:173 (message):
  Project 'davis_ros_driver' tried to find library 'pthread'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'roscpp'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory containing its
  code is included?
```

This problem has been bothering me for a week. I tried many solutions, such as changing the Cmake version to 3.10.0 and 3.12.4, but it still didn't work, so I feel very desperate. I hope someone will help me.

Any suggestions from everyone will help me. Thanks

Melodic  ros    Ubuntu18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392435/project-%27davis_ros_driver%27-tried-to-find-library-%27pthread%27.--the-library-is---neither-a-target-nor-built/installed-properly./) by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-12-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-08**:
Hi @luna wu, have you looked at this: https://answers.ros.org/question/297753/cannot-build-a-package/

**Comment by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) on 2021-12-08**:
Yes, I have tried this :

```
Using compile options via CMakeLists.txt worked for me add_compile_options(-pthread)
```

But it didn't work for me.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-09**:
I tried to replicate your error a couple times but I was unable to reproduce, it compiles with no issues. Perhaps start with a fresh installation of ROS Melodic and Ubuntu 18.04 as the owners of this library are not very responsive.

**Comment by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) on 2021-12-09**:
Thank you very much for your attention to this issue.

Because of too many problems ,I  reinstalled the Ubuntu 18.04 version, and the recompilation was successful without any errors.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-09**:
Glad it worked. Please document as an answer so others may benefit in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since I did not solve this problem , I reinstalled the Ubuntu 18.04 version, and the recompilation was successful without any errors...

I think, sometimes, reinstalling the system is faster than solving the problem

---

Originally posted by [luna wu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90459/luna-wu/) with karma: 46 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0